# To add Life to date measures with a date slicer on the report

Tags: powerbi

I am facing this issue in understanding how to add a measure Amount LTD which looks back to all the data for projects since its start.
I am able to give total amounts per project between the dates on the data slicer but unable to get Amount which looks back beyond the data filters applied and get the LTD sum value till the to date selected on the date slicer.
Can someone please help.
TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this [Cumulative Total](https://www.daxpatterns.com/cumulative-total/) pattern.

> ```
> Cumulative Quantity :=
> CALCULATE (
>     SUM ( Transactions[Quantity] ),
>     FILTER (
>         ALL ( 'Date'[Date] ),
>         'Date'[Date] <= MAX ( 'Date'[Date] )
>     )
> )
> ```